# Gradle build finished with 75 error(s) in 30 sec in android studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am getting errors as below when i tried running my module,

```
Error:Gradle: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:Gradle: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
[...]
```

In the project there are two modules ModuleA & ModuleB
ModuleA is library. ModuleB depend on ModuleA

Build.gradle file of ModuleA

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Build.gradle file of ModuleB

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.td.tdabslidingmenu"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
    compile project(':sample-users')
}
```

i tried commenting     compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
and           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
separately as mentioned in other threads for each Run but no use...

Comment: Why are you using both ActionBarSherlock and AppCompat? ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated for quite some time and you should not be using it any more.

Comment: yes it was an old code, now i wanted to add some features to ModuleB(old one)   and those features i am importing from ModuleA in the form of library.. in this case how to proceede with this..

Answer (score 1):

search your project for (cmd+shift+f) `titleTextStyle` where is this being declared is it you or is it in something external you are using

the issue is in xml attributes being defined twice. Can have multiple causes. The obvious one being check your `styles.xml` and `attrs.xml`

Next remove the double compile of `'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'`

I would also `targetSdkVersion 21` for all modules

Comment: As i read other threads error is bcz i am using              compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' and  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'                  how do i avoid that in my case??

Answer (score 0):

you need to comment compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+', as said Tanis.7x - "ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated for quite some time and you should not be using it any more"